# Codemirror editor fullscreen - how to add custom functions to code mirror

Tags: javascript, codemirror

There is a nice [example of how to make a fullscreen version of the CodeMirror editor](http://codemirror.net/demo/fullscreen.html). However this is not going to work if the CodeMirror widget is in the middle of some other `position: absolute` or `relative` div (the CodeMirror widget's absolute positioning won't be relative to the entire page anymore).

We can add a new command to CodeMirror to go fullscreen:

```
CodeMirror.commands.fullscreen = function (cm)
{
var fs_p = $(cm.getWrapperElement());

if ( cm._ic3Fullscreen == null) {
    cm._ic3Fullscreen = false;
    cm._ic3container = fs_p.parent();
}

if (!cm._ic3Fullscreen)
{
    fs_p = fs_p.detach();
    fs_p.addClass("CodeMirrorFullscreen");
    fs_p.appendTo("body");
    cm.focus();
    cm._ic3Fullscreen = true;
}
else
{
    fs_p = fs_p.detach();
    fs_p.removeClass("CodeMirrorFullscreen");
    fs_p.appendTo(cm._ic3container);
    cm.focus();
    cm._ic3Fullscreen = false;
}
};
```

After we need to bind this new command when creating the CodeMirror. Add this to the options:

```
extraKeys: {"F11": "fullscreen"}
```

The question is what to put in the `CodeMirrorFullscreen` CSS class to make sure fullscreen will work?

Comment: "on how to make a fullscreen version" - fullscreen version of what? Your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: fix to be a bit clearer, if you know codemirror you understand the question as it's also part of their demos.

Comment: please elaborate on this. what do you mean by "absolute position might not be anymore the screen"?

Answer (score 1):

Using `position: fixed` instead of `absolute` should do the trick.

To test it out, just modify the CSS of CodeMirror's fullscreen.html demo as follows:

```
  form {
    position: relative;
  }
  .CodeMirror-fullscreen {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
  }
```

(The added `form` selector is not part of the solution. It's just there to make sure we're testing the case you care about – where using `position: absolute` in `.CodeMirror-fullscreen` doesn't work).

Answer (score 0):

I used codeMirror5 with ReactJs in this exact same situation, all I did was to import the fullscreen styling and it worked.

```
import 'codemirror/addon/display/fullscreen.js'
import 'codemirror/addon/display/fullscreen.css'
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).